# how manage.py can start the iteration of flask

Tags: flask

I am making a price tracker.My project structure is this:

```
Myapp-folder     
    manage.py-from flask script module     
    subApp-folder
        __init__.py 
        form.py 
        models.py 
        views.py 
        pricemonitor-folder 
            main.py    
            __init__.py 
            send_email.py 
            price_compare_sendemail.py-with class Compare_sendemail and start_monitor function
```

In the main.py, I have an interation to compare the prices every 60s and send-email if needed.

```
from app.PriceMonitor.price_compare_sendmail import Compare_sendemail
break_time = 60  # set waiting time for one crawl round
monitor = Compare_sendemail()
monitor.start_monitor(break_time)
```

The manage.py is as below:

```
from flask_script import Manager, Server
from app import app, db
manager = Manager(app)
manager.add_command("runserver",Server(host='127.0.0.1', port=5000, use_debugger=True))
if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager.run()
```

But the iteration doesn't work when I run `python manage.py runserver` while I directly run the main.py successfully. How can I make up code to run the flask server with the compare_sendemail iteration running at the background? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for **Celery.**
you can use **Celery background task**. If your application has a long running task, such as processing some uploaded data or sending email, you don’t want to wait for it to finish during a request. Instead, use a task queue to send the necessary data to another process that will run the task in the background while the request returns immediately.

here you can find documentation for celery
https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/celery/

and if you want to wait for Task to complete you can use Coroutines and Tasks

https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html

there are other options for flask background task
like

**RQ**
https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-xxii-background-jobs

some other Alternatives
https://smirnov-am.github.io/background-jobs-with-flask/

**Threads**

**uWSGI thread**

**uWSGI spooler**
uSWGI spooler is great for simple tasks. like sending OTP SMS or Email.

Comment: Thanks a lot.There are so many of them.I will check the options later.

Comment: I had a look at apscheduler because it looks quite simple. I can use it to schedule my task. Thanks for that. Another problem popped up was how can I start the scheduled task in my manage.py which is from flask-script module. Sorry I am not familiar with flask script.

Answer (score 0):

I answer part of my own question.
In the main.py, I used while loop and time module to iterate the price_compare_sendemail.py
every 60s. While this is not an ideal background task  handler, this project is currently just for my own usage so it is OK for me. My original thought was using the flask script manager to handle all the python commands-I don't know if it is the right thought though because I just started to learn Flask.
After some google search, I found the way to use manager.

```
from subapp.pricemonitor.main import Start_monitor
Monitor=Start_monitor()
@manager.command
def monitor_start():
    break_time=10
    Monitor.start_monitoring(break_time)
```

Then use the command 'python manage.py monitor_start' to start the background task. I don't know if it is useful but at least it fit my original thought.